# How to create a proper simpleXML object?

Tags: php, simplexml

I have been trying to figure out why this can't be properly executed but after much trial and error and consulting PHP documentation I haven't got it right yet.

For some reason when using this url (www.elfinanciero.com.mx/rss/) as a src for a simpleXML object, it won't work. If the url is substituted for: www.razon.com.mx/spip.php?page=backend_rubrique&id_rubrique=2 it works perfectly. This is happening over and over through several urls, some work some don't. The problem is that I am not being able to even echo the errors when it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

```
$src = "www.elfinanciero.com.mx/rss/";   
$doc = simplexml_load_file($src) or die ("Error: can't create object");
var_dump($doc);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
if (false === $doc ) {
   echo "Failed loading XML: ";
   foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
       echo "<br>", $error->message;
   }
} else {
   print_r($doc);
}
```

Comment: `simplexml_load_file("src)` syntax error here

Comment: since you say this only happens with one URL, I guess that the extra quote character and missing semicolon and dollar character are a problems that only exist in your question, right? also, it's probably safer to use a full URL (with its corresponding protocol schema)

Comment: excuse the syntax mistakes, I've corrected them, nonetheless the issue goes on as the code I was using has no mistakes of this kind

Comment: By "doesn't work", what do you mean exactly? If you're not seeing error messages, what are you seeing? Note that `var_dump` and `print_r` are not very good at showing the contents of SimpleXMLElement objects.

Comment: @IMSoP I'm seeing a blank page, absolutely nothing, no errors no nothing. For some reason it is not being processed or something crashes along the way.

Comment: One thing I notice is that you're setting the error handling mode (`libxml_use_internal_errors`) *after* parsing the document; you need to set it *before* `simplexml_load_file`, or it won't do anything.

Comment: After moving it to the top and removing the 'or die' part, as such

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$src = "http://www.elfinanciero.com.mx/rss/";   
$doc = simplexml_load_file($src) ;
if (false === $doc ) {
   echo "Failed loading XML: ";
   foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
       echo "<br>", $error->message;
   }
} else {
   echo "SUCCESS!";
}

I get this:
Failed loading XML: 
failed to load external entity "http://www.elfinanciero.com.mx/rss/"

Answer (score 1):

You have to add semicolon in $src, and call to the variable with $
Should be something like this:

```
$src = "www.elfinanciero.com.mx/rss/";
$doc = simplexml_load_file($src) or die ("Error: can't create object");
var_dump($doc);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
if (false === $doc ) {
   echo "Failed loading XML: ";
   foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
       echo "<br>", $error->message;
   }
} else {
   print_r($doc);
}
```